# Is (in) the correct preposition in "... the real poverty is in manners..."?

Tags: prepositions, sentence-construction

I want to say the following sentence as a way of comforting a poor person.

The sentence:

> There is no shame in *it* since the real poverty is in manners rather
>   than in money.

*it* refers to the fact that s/he is poor.

> There is no shame in *being poor* since the real poverty is in manners rather
>   than in money.

I'm not sure of the preposition **in** in the sentence, I intend the first one as it is a part of a dialogue where the person mentioned their state before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you're using **in** correctly, the contrast you have set up does not work particularly well, namely, "manners" versus "money".

I think you are saying that poverty consists in a *lack* of manners not in a lack of money, that wealth is of the mind, not of the pocket.

A poor person might reply "I will remind my children of that truth the next time they tell me they are hungry".

Answer (score 2):

*In* sounds fine here, and it's the word I would use (for something like "the real poverty is in manners")

It would definitely be good to see some context, though. What do you mean by the sentence? That money is not as important as manners?

Comment: I mean by it that the people who lack manners are the ones who have to be called "poor" or "indigent" since, as you nearly said, manners are more important than money. It is just a philosophy/opinion. There is no context that that sentence depends on. Thanks for the answer.